# fool-proof checking if input is int with try loop

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

New to programming. Python3. Testing options to check if input is an intiger. Input can be either positive or negative number.

Went for try loop. Problem: if user inputs e.g. a char (letter) two times program goes to next line. I guess I should pack it in another loop or maybe there is a simpler/prettier solution? As input can also be a negative number do not want to use .isdigit()

My code so far:

```
print("Hi, I will count for you.")

initial_number = input("Please enter the first number ")

try:
    initial_number = int(initial_number)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter an intiger.")
    initial_number = input("Please enter the first number ")

last_number = input("Please enter the last number ")
try:
    last_number = int(last_number)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter an intiger. ")
    last_number = input("Please enter the last number")

between = input("Please enter the pseudo-iterator ")
try: 
    between = int(between)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter an intiger. ")
    between = input("Please enter the pseudo-iterator. ")

for number in range(int(initial_number), int(last_number)+1, int(between)):
    print(number)
```

edit: Did not realize that loop has not been properly initialized. Thank you for help!

Comment: Which do you want: digits or integers?

Comment: Intigers. Sorry, English is not my first lg. Thanks for pointing out the difference. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't written try *loops*, but doing so looks like it would accomplish what you want.  Something like:

```
while True:
    try:
        initial_number = int(input("Please enter the first number "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer.")
```

Comment: It does! Thank you for correcting my assumption about having the loop part. :)